# Send JSON in Post with robospice google http client

Tags: android, json, post, robospice, google-http-client

I have a problem with creating post requests and send json with Robospice google http java client. My problem is, that the server receives an empty request data. (Nothing in postData)

```
@Override
    public AjaxResult loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {  

        JsonHttpContent jsonHttpContent = new JsonHttpContent(new JacksonFactory(), jsonObject);

        //ByteArrayContent.fromString("application/json", jsonObject.toString())
        HttpRequest request = getHttpRequestFactory().buildPostRequest(
                new GenericUrl(baseUrl),            
                jsonHttpContent);


        request.getHeaders().setContentType("application/json");

        request.setParser(new JacksonFactory().createJsonObjectParser());

        request.setContent(jsonHttpContent);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = request.execute();

        AjaxResult result =  httpResponse.parseAs(getResultType());

        return result;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: robospice, google http java client!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
public class SignIn_Request extends GoogleHttpClientSpiceRequest<Login> {
    private String apiUrl;
    private JSONObject mJsonObject;

    public SignIn_Request(JSONObject mJsonObject) {
    super(Login.class);
    this.apiUrl = AppConstants.GLOBAL_API_BASE_ADDRESS + AppConstants.API_SIGN_IN;
    this.mJsonObject = mJsonObject;
    }

    @Override
    public Login loadDataFromNetwork() throws IOException {
    Ln.d("Call web service " + apiUrl);
    HttpRequest request = getHttpRequestFactory()//
        .buildPostRequest(new GenericUrl(apiUrl), ByteArrayContent.fromString("application/json", mJsonObject.toString()));
    request.setParser(new JacksonFactory().createJsonObjectParser());
    return request.execute().parseAs(getResultType());
    }

}
```

Convert your JSON into byte array and include it in your post request.

Answer (score 0):

I've been hunting around for a similar solution myself and I found a decent explanation of how  Google want you to format the content.

I made POJO class and just added some getters and setters and used that for the data and it seemed to work for me.

[google-http-java-client json update existing object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273798/google-http-java-client-json-update-existing-object?rq=1)